# Memory leak in stateless session

Tags: memory, drools, workbench, stateless, kie-server

I am working with Business Central version 7.61.0.Final and KIE Server version 7.61.0.Final. I created my project using Decision Tables and deployed it to KIE Server. I execute my rules through the KIE Server REST API. The KIE session is **stateless**, so the facts must be automatically removed at the end of the request.
[kie base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6JUe.png)
[kie session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Jx7g.png)

My problem is that the memory is increasing and never eliminated. So, when I run stress tests (for example, 1000 requests) the server collapse.

The memory usage before tests is 31% and after tests (1000 requests) is 74%
[memory before tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfEQc.png)
[memory after tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GenyU.png)

I tried to change the deployment settings (Runtime Strategy equal to **Per request**, Persistence Mode equal to **None**, and Audit Mode equal to **None**) to these values, but the memory continues to increase
[deployment settings 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQoOu.png)
[deployment settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HThtO.png)

I hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have a similar issue.